# How to disable Turbolinks in a specific page?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I have an issue with a script only working when refreshing the page and so I'm trying to disable Turbolinks for only that page. The code below doesn't work. However, if I add the "data-no-turbolink" attribute directly to the body tag in application.html.erb it works. How do I disable Turbolinks in my view? I have followed the solution posted here, [Rails 4: disable Turbolinks in a specific page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22326473/rails-4-disable-turbolinks-in-a-specific-page)  but I can't get it to work.

I have the gem 'jquery-turbolinks' installed.

policy.html.erb

```
<% content_for :body do %>
 <% if controller.controller_name == 'pages' && controller.action_name == 'policy' %>
  <body data-no-turbolink="true">
 <% end %>
<% end %>

<div class="row">
 <div class="small-12 medium-8 large-7 columns end">
  <a href="//www.com/" class="nostyle" title="Policy">Policy</a>
  <script>(function (w,d) {var loader = function () {var s = d.createElement("script"), tag = d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; s.src = "//cdn.java.com/java.js"; tag.parentNode.insertBefore(s,tag);}; if(w.addEventListener){w.addEventListener("load", loader, false);}else if(w.attachEvent){w.attachEvent("onload", loader);}else{w.onload = loader;}})(window, document); 
  </script>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In Turbolinks 5 use `data-turbolinks="false"`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use this oneliner in your layout:

```
<body <%= "data-no-turbolinks='true'".html_safe if controller_name=="pages" && action_name=="policy" %>>
```

But the other way to do it, which I use mostly, would be to put this chunk of code to the links leading to this page...

So, let's suppose your route is named `:policy`, you should do this:

```
<%= link_to "Policy", policy_path, :"data-no-turbolink" => true %>
```

**Long time has gone, here is an update**

Recently, I have started using `turbolinks 5.0 beta`, by:

```
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5.0.0.beta'
```

It gets far easier... All `document ready` javascript gets loaded, no problem... All you have to do is add a listener to the load event.

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', named_function );
var named_function = function() {
    // thinks to do on document load
}
```

You don't have to also add

```
$(document).ready(function (){
     // stuff
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(named_function);
```

Because `Turbolinks` will gracefully fall back to `document load` if the page is hard loaded.

Comment: I used your second method and it works great. Thanks.

Comment: If you happen to use CoffeeScript, simply replace your (common) first line `$ ->` with `$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->`

Comment: more sexy format:

<%= link_to "Policy", policy_path, data: {'no-turbolink' => true} %>

Comment: Is this still valid for TL5?

Comment: @brad, the lower part of the answer is pretty much it.

Comment: That doesn't disable it though, that's just hooking into the load event?

Comment: I'm getting issues with html5 videos still loading on pages after a turbolink, so want to disable it for them pages

Comment: You should post a question with your issue. There has to be something that can be fixed there

Answer (score 16):

For turbolinks 5 if you use this method mentioned above:

```
    <%= link_to "Policy", policy_path, :"data-no-turbolink" => true %>
```

You'll need to change it to:

```
    <%= link_to "Policy", policy_path, :"data-turbolinks" => false %>
```

Comment: And in HAML it needs to be `:'data-turbolinks' => 'false'`

Comment: That's why I hate stackoverflow sometimes. Outdated/old-version answer has more up-votes and still marked as "best answer". Thank you Thomas for the turbolinks5 clarification!

Answer (score 8):

I tried the other methods mentioned here to no avail, but from the Turbolinks 5 docs, you can insert this meta tag on the page that you want to always load without Turbolinks.

```
<meta name="turbolinks-visit-control" content="reload">
```

Adding a data attribute to all links means that you have to know where all those links are, which is brittle if you have a situation where there might be inline links in user-created content.

The body tag data attribute method didn't work for me as I'd expect it to - I'd have assumed that loading a turbolinks-supported page and then clicking a link to go to a page where you want to disable turbolinks would result in a full, standard page load. That didn't seem to be the case, especially with back button or history navigation.

Adding this meta tag forces Turbolinks 5 to do a full page reload before it attempts to insert any content into the dom. You get that classic flash of a blank page, but if like me, you're using external Javascript that needs to fire without interference from Turbolinks, that's the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 6):

this is going sound really simple

```
<%- if params[:controller] == 'controller_name' and params[:action] == 'index' %>
  <body data-no-turbolink="true">
<%- else %>
  <body data-no-turbolink="false">
<%- end %>
```

I hope this help.

Comment: In Turbolinks5, use `<body data-turbolinks="false">` instead.

Answer (score 2):

For the last Turbolinks, I've to add both add:

```
<meta name="turbolinks-visit-control" content="reload">
```

in the `<head>` and:

```
 <body data-turbolinks="false">
```

in place of the `<body>` tag to fully disable Turbolinks for a specific page.

Answer (score 1):

To turn off turbolink for a specific link

```
<a href="/" data-turbolinks="false"></a>
```