# Click not triggering for modal in IE Edge

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, onclick, dom-events, microsoft-edge

I am having trouble opening a modal in Microsoft Edge only.

The link to open the modal is:

```
<%= link_to the_path, class: "btn btn-tertiary class-used-to-find-the-link", data: {"things-id" => 4, "other-things-id" => 7} do %>
  <span>The Link's Text</span>
<% end %>
```

The JavaScript for the link is:

```
$('class-used-to-find-the-link').click(onClick);
```

The `onClick` method mentioned above would be something like:

```
onClick   =   function(event) { 
                 //blah..blah...blah
              };
```

The `.click` does not get triggered in IE Edge only but works in all other browsers. This link above is supposed to open a modal. I have other instances of `.click` that don't open modals and these are fine.

So, I think it may be related to the discussion here: [Microsoft Edge: onclick event stops working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33525721/microsoft-edge-onclick-event-stops-working). Similar to the post linked, when I refresh the page the link does work and the modal opens.

Also, if I firstly open the page that contains the link to click in another tab, via right click and 'Open In New Tab', then the link will also work.

I have tried some of the answers in the post I have linked, including `mousedown` and `mouseup` but these didn't work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It says the bug is fixed in build 34.x https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/5782378/.

Comment: I am not 100% sure that my issue is the same as the one linked in my question. Also my Microsoft Edge version is 38.14393.0.0 and Microsoft EdgeHTML is 14.14393.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was being caused by Turbolinks and was not related to the SO question and answer here: [Microsoft Edge: onclick event stops working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33525721/microsoft-edge-onclick-event-stops-working). So, in a way the comment of the link here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/5782378/ was valid.

I disabled Turbolinks in the same fashion and in the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27196250/1945948

Specifically, the issue was being caused by how turbolinks and event handlers combine. An alternative to disabling Turbolinks would be to use delegated event handling. Here, is a good article on delegated event handlers: https://www.iexposure.com/industry-insights/rails-4-turbolinks-and-delegated-event-handling-in-jquery.